# Using EF Core EntityTypeBuilder with nested/complex properties

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have something like the `TrackingMetrics` entity below (with more logic and methods in practice), but I'm having trouble figuring out the syntax for mapping this to the database using entity framework.

At the end of the day, I want to track the response to each metric as a column, but setting up a complex grandchild like relationship with EF is giving me trouble.

I have one of several `EntityTypeBuilder` configurations I've tried to get this to work to no avail. Anyone done something like this before?

```cs
public class TrackingMetrics 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public PrimaryMetrics PrimaryMetrics { get; private set; }
}

public class PrimaryMetrics : ValueObject
{
    public MetricOne MetricOne { get; set; }
    public MetricTwo MetricOne { get; set; }

    public PrimaryMetrics()
    {
        MetricOne.Set("Unanswered");
        MetricTwo.Set("Unanswered");
    }
}


public class MetricOne : ValueObject, IMetric
{
    public Response Response { get; private set; }
    public void Set(Response response)
    {
        Response = response;
    }
}


public class MetricTwo : ValueObject, IMetric
{
    public Response Response { get; private set; }
    public void Set(Response response)
    {
        Response = response;
    }
}

public class Response : ValueObject
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public sealed class PrimaryMetricsConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PrimaryMetrics>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PrimaryMetrics> builder)
    {        
        builder.OwnsOne(x => x.PrimaryMetrics, opts =>
        {
            opts.Property(x => x.MetricOne.Response)
                .HasConversion(x => x.Value, x => new Response(x))
                .HasColumnName("primary_metrics_metric_one_response");
            opts.Property(x => x.MetricTwo.Response)
                .HasConversion(x => x.Value, x => new Response(x))
                .HasColumnName("primary_metrics_metric_two_response");
        }).Navigation(x => x.PrimaryMetrics)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

This is the actual error I get:

> The expression 'x => x.MetricOne.Response' is not a valid member access expression. The expression should represent a simple property or field access: 't => t.MyProperty'. (Parameter 'memberAccessExpression')

Comment: Nested owned entities are definitely supported. You have so many layers here. Can you peel them away until it succeeds and then add back in one at a time to see which one is breaking it? I can't offer much more...brain-fog COVID at the moment. This is as much brain power as I can muster

Comment: yeah, that was what I figured, but I don't see any kind of `owns` option once you're on the child property. there's more to each of these that i took away to make an attempt at making it easier to grok, but get why it's still hard even not sick (hope you feel better!!). The part that's breaking it is the syntax I'm using for nesting it, so not sure what to do there while using this model. closest I've came so far is to update each `MetricXXXX` prop to be a string EF can understand and backing it with the VO, but it's... an annoying amount of extra work

Comment: IIRC you have to configure them together. I know I've done it. Can't remember where so can't put my finger on an example of the config.

Comment: here's an example I stole from a github issue easier than finding my own right now: 
  builder.OwnsOne(root => root.Address1, address =>
            {
                address.OwnsOne(a => a.SubAddress, subAddress =>
                {
                    subAddress.OwnsOne(it => it.SubSubAddress);
                });
            });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can't format in comments so here it is again:

```
builder.OwnsOne(root => root.Address1, address =>
            {
                address.OwnsOne(a => a.SubAddress, subAddress =>
                {
                    subAddress.OwnsOne(it => it.SubSubAddress);
                });
            });
```

Comment: oo this looks promising 

Comment: that was it guess was the only spot i didn't look for an `ownsone` extension, but it makes complete sense. thanks and hope you feel better!